# Java Callback function or static class

Tags: java, lambda, callback

I'm creating a game and I'm stuck in this problem:

I have the class Game and inside the Game, I have the Kitchen.
When the player type for example: /new egg I do: game.kitchen.newEgg()

I would like to know what is the best way, and how I can notify the game that the Egg is finished.

I tried putting the class Game as static, but is doesn't seem correct.

I also tried every 1 second the game call kitchen.isReady() (neither this looks like correct)

and my last try was create a Consumer like this:

```
public class Kitchen {
    public void newEgg(String name, Consumer<String> function){
        System.out.println("egg is in progress");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        function.accept(name);
    }
}
```

and in the game:

```
public void createEgg(String eggName){
    System.out.println("Creating an Egg");
    Kitchen egg = new Kitchen();
    Gamex x = new Gamex();
    Runnable task2 = () -> { egg.newEgg(eggName, x::eggCreated); };
    new Thread(task2).start();
    System.out.println("game continue...");
}

public void eggCreated(String eggName) {
    System.out.println("Egg: " + eggName + " finished.");
}
```

All the tree methods worked, but Is this the proper way to do? 
How I should do it? 
What is the best solution for a game?

Comment: It is still unclear what your intentions are. Do mention that you are dealing with concurrent programming, and describe each of your active entities.

Comment: You're not calling `newEgg()` anywhere. And where's `egg.applyFunction()`? And what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I fixed the method names. Sorry.
@E_net4: I have the engine (game) that contains a kitchen. the kitchen is responsible to create the egg. and when it finishes I would like to notify the game for some reasons (update the user points, decrease the money... etc...) My question is: What is the best way to it? One of my suggestions? other thing complete different? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being notified that an asynchronous job is done would be a job for a `CompletableFuture<V>` (Java 8). 
It is quite like a `Future<V>`, only you can attach to it additional callbacks that get triggered immediately when the job completes.

Here is a minimal working example that you could adapt to your game engine :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example example = new Example();

        // Start generating a String
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);     // We need some pool to run things async
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(example::createString, pool)  // run the creation job in another thread
                         .thenAccept(example::callback);            // run this callback when the job is done
        pool.shutdown();

        // Doing something else in the meantime...
        System.out.println("Meandering...");

    }

    private String createString() {
        artificialDelay();
        return "Hello World";
    }

    private void callback(String input) {
        System.out.println("Received this : " + input);
    }

    private void artificialDelay() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I liked it.  but why is it better than my solution with     `Runnable task = () -> { egg.newEgg(eggName, x::eggCreated); };
    new Thread(task).start();`.

Comment: In your code, the `newEgg` method does 2 things : create an egg, and orchestrate what happens after (here, pass the egg to a consumer).
But what if you want to transform the egg before consuming it ? Or if you want to run the callback asynchronously, in another thread?
The `CompletableFuture` framework allows you to do just that : compose (sync or async) a pipeline to create, transform and consume data without being intrusive to the business methods.